# Order sorting of an ndarray by indexes in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

want to sort np.ndarray indexes of an array such as

```
[[.5,.7, .9], [.6, .0, .8]]
```

result would look like this

```
[[1,1],[0,1],[1,0],[0,1],[1,2],[0,3]]
```

applying those indexes will get correct sorting order and at same time can be applied to other structures that match the data.

I tried np.argsort, but that doesn't give indexes for ndarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use np.argsort on the flat array and then use np.divmod to get the indexes of your previous shape.
Edit: np.unravel_index is the divmod alternative for higher dimensions, see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html

Comment: I did ```zip(*np.unravel_index(np.argsort(arr, axis=None), arr.shape))``` to get that output. Thank you

Comment: You could also cast the unraveled output to an array and use the transpose instead of zipping.